# Remove row in csv format containing cell 'NULL' in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a solution in Java that removes a row if one of the cells contain a NULL, such as row with the name Jenny. The table is given in CSV format.Every two consecutive cells in each row are separated by a single comma ',' symbol. Every two
consecutive rows are separated by a new-line '\n' symbol. For example, the table from the task statement, written in CSV format, is the single string:

```
"id,name,age,score\n1,Jack,NULL,12\n17,Betty,28,11".
```

You may assume that each row has the same number of cells. Need to watch out for words such as 'ANNULLED'.

1. Given `S = "id,name,age,score\n1,Jenny,NULL,14\n17,Daryll,31,11"`, your function should return `"id,name,age,score\n17,Betty,28,11"`.

```
+----+-------+------+-------+
| id | name  | age  | score |
+----+-------+------+-------+
| 1b | Jenny | NULL | 14    |
+----+-------+------+-------+
| 17 | Daryll| 32   | 11    |
+----+-------+------+-------+
```

My solution has been marked as only 33 out of 100 efficiency wise and I wonder if anyone could advise how I can improve my solution please.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String S = "id,name,age,score\n1,Jack,NULL,12\n17,Betty,28,11";
    System.out.println(solution(S));
}


public static String solution(String S) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] rows = S.split("\n");
    String finalString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        al.add(rows[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        if (al.get(i).contains(",NULL,") || al.get(i).contains("NULL\n") || al.get(i).contains(",NULL")) {
            al.remove(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        finalString += al.get(i) + "\n";
    }
    
    String finalerString = finalString.substring(0, finalString.length() - 1);
    return finalerString;
}
```

Comment: Apologies! I have edited it now

Comment: You don't need to make so many iterations,  think how you could do it in 1 iteration after you split by \n.

Comment: you should use Arrays.asList(your array) to get the arraylist , then  idk why are you doing too many or's (||) , you should just use just  .contains("NULL"), why to use the "\n" and "," and you can use list.foreach and add the "\n", from three loops you have you will get just 1.

Comment: or's are needed for 'ANNULLED' but you could use a regex.

Comment: Can anyone give answer in swift language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of efficiency, the most efficient solution would be iterating over the input String, `S` once and, writing the solution into a stream. Now let's compare it with your implementation.

- `S.split("\n");` requires full iteration over `S` pulse you create additional memory of the size of `S`
- `al.add(rows[i]);` you convert the String array to List, I don't see any need for that, but I don't think it affects the performance much.
- `al.get(i).contains(",NULL,")` that iterate over the entire String, and you got three such conditions, so you iterate over `S` three times here(in the worst case since if the first `or` condition is true the others will not be checked).
- `finalString += al.get(i) + "\n";` Here you are reconstructing the solution without the filtered rows. The problem with `+=` on `String`s is that it each time creates a new instance of the `String`. This makes your implementation `O(N^2)` instead of `O(N)`. Switch to a `StringBuilder` and you will return into the `O(N)` space. With modern ADE like IntelliJ, you will get a warning and it will update your code automatically.
- `finalString.substring(0, finalString.length() - 1);` Again in here you are creating a new instance of the String so it costs you `S`

To implement a simple-efficient solution I would do the following

- Split `S` by `\n` as you did
- Iterate over the String array and filter out the rows with `Null`
- Then use a `StringBuilder` to combine the results

For the filtering I would do something like:

```
al.get(i).startsWith("NULL\n") || al.get(i).endsWith(",NULL") || al.get(i).contains(",NULL,")
```

The methods `startsWith`, `endsWith` are `O(1)` compare to `contains` that is `O(N)`, so the filtering will be O(1) in the best case and O(N) in the worst case.

As I said earlier this will not be the most efficient solution, but it is pretty simple and pretty efficient. It requires only two iterations over `S` in the worst case.

Comment: Can anyone give answer in swift language.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is to just work on the string form.

Here's how to perform the requested operation with a regular expression, which I admit is not the most efficient way to work on the string, but still shouldn't be too bad:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data = "id,name,age,score\n1,Jenny,NULL,14\n17,Daryll,31,11";

        Pattern exp = Pattern.compile("^(.*,)*NULL(,.*)*(\\n|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        String r = exp.matcher(data).replaceAll("");
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

I'm not much of a regex weenie.  There's likely a more concise regular expression than this, but this gives you the idea and it does work.

Result:

```
id,name,age,score
17,Daryll,31,11
```

Comment: I doubt that regex is the most efficient way. I bet that using a stream and filter those nulls with a Heap buffer would be many times more efficient. Of course, regex is a way more elegant way to go, as you demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I updated my answer to make it clear that working directly on the string was my idea for efficiency rather than using a regex.  I just didn't want to write a bunch of code to show that main point. I agree that there are more efficient ways, but regex isn't all that slow in real life, where you compile the regex once and use it a bunch of times.  That's why they're compiled. There are likely more efficient expressions as well. So for a real case, I wouldn't guess that regex is generally "many times" less efficient.

Comment: Can anyone give answer in swift language.